# Suggesting edits in recommendation letter

Tags: etiquette, recommendation-letter

I asked a professor months earlier for a recommendation letter for a summer school, he accepted but in turn, he asked me to draft my own recommendation letter, I did that since I was only applying for summer school that usually admits most students. Now, I asked the same professor for a recommendation letter for a prestigious research internship application. And he sent me the attached letter with these words-

*"I have attached please check whether I had made any mistake in your accomplishments. If it is ok for you let me know I will upload  it."*

Now since it's a prestigious research internship, I am not satisfied with the letter. Some of the statements are even copied from the previous LOR that I have drafted for him about myself, he only listed the things I have done so far that too without much emphasizing those points which make me a better candidate for doing research work like my previous projects, and there are spelling mistakes too. Should I point these things out in reply mail and ask him to edit? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is OK to ask for some changes, but don't be too demanding. If the parts he copied from the previous LOR are true, there is nothing wrong with that.

I would say something like: "Thank you. There are no mistakes in my list of accomplishments, but this is a prestigious research internship that is more competitive than the summer school. Would it be possible for you to write a sentence or two about my work on projects A and B, or some points that might make me a strong candidate? (There are a few spelling mistakes: ...)" Then finish with some other expression of gratitude.